# JAVA program to calculate the sum of first n even numbers starting from 0 which are divisible by 3 and print the sum

Tags: java, arrays

I need java code to calculate the sum of first n even numbers starting from 0 which are divisible by 3 and print the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_3 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n=sc.nextInt();
       int sum=0;
       for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
       {
         if(i%2==0)
         {
           if(i%3==0)
           {
             sum=sum+i;
           }
         }
       }
       System.out.print(""+sum);
   }
 }
```

This code only gives me answer only up to number 10 divisible by 3 (it gives answer 6) where as i need sum of first 10 even number divisible by 3 i need answer 36.(first 10 even number are 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20 so that sum is 6+12+18=36)

Comment: Make a while loop and count how many times you found a match and break the loop on N matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int sum=0;
        int even =0;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
            if(even%3==0) {
                sum=sum+even;
            }
            even=even +2;
        }
        System.out.print(""+sum);
    }
}
```

**I'm assuming you want to see the first 10 even numbers and sum only the ones that are divided by 3.**
This will do the work. The problem is that you were only checking until the number 10. You should had a integer that would increment +2, avoiding having one more if condition.
I hope i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop and count how many matches you found:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise1_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int matches = 0

        while(matches < n) {
            i++;
            if(i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) { 
            //or as mentioned in other answer use if(i % 6 == 0) {
                sum += i;
                matches++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("%d", sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An even number that's divisible by 3 is a multiple of 6. Therefore, you can adapt the formula for triangular numbers (`n*(n+1)/2`) to solve this problem in O(1) complexity and avoid any loops:

```
public int sumOfMultiplesOfSix(int num) {
  return 3 * num * (num + 1);
}
```

Hence, to look at the first *n* even numbers, you can simply divide your input by 3:

```
public int sumOfEvenCandidates(int numberOfCandidates) {
  return sumOfMultiplesOfSix(numberOfCandidates / 3);
}
```

Comment: Close, but by "first 10" he means out of the first 10 even numbers, not the first 10 valid numbers; So an input of 3 should give 6, not 36. You can essentially just divide by 3 to bound the input this way and still use your math, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split enter a limit from the console and calculation.
In a simple case, you have to generate an [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with step 2 and the required number of elements, filter out once that divisible by 3 and sum them.

```
public static int getSum(int max) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0, val = 2; i <= max; i++, val += 2)
        if (val % 3 == 0)
            sum += val;

    return sum;
}
```

---

This is an example using streams.

```
public static int getSum(int max) {
    return IntStream.iterate(2, val -> val + 2).limit(max)
                    .filter(val -> val % 3 == 0)
                    .sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did a small modification to your code by introducing a different for loop breaking condition.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n=sc.nextInt();
   int sum=0;
   int matches=0;
   for(int i=0;matches<=n;i++)
   {
     if(i%2==0 && i%3==0)
     {
         sum=sum+i;
         matches++;
     }
   }
   System.out.print(""+sum);
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code, just give the input as 20, you will get the desired answer. You are iterating from 0 to n incrementing 1 at a time, so if you give input as 10 it will go  from 1 to 10 only. If you want something else then please re frame your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple. change the for loop sentence from 
"for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)"
to
"for(int i=0;i<=(2*n);i++)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<=(2*n-2);i+=6){
            sum=sum+i;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_3 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n=sc.nextInt();
      int sum=0;
//Use for or while loop do the operation.
for(int i=0;i<=n*2;i+=2){
   if(i%3==0){
    sum+=i;
}
}
  
System.out.print(sum);
}
}
```

Hope this will help, As we need only even numbers double the max number so when you what the sum of 10 even numbers it will calculate the sum of even numbers up to 20.

Answer (score 0):

Consider First n even numbers starting from zero(0).Complete the code segment to calculate sum of  all the numbers divisible by 3 from 0 to n. Print the sum.

```
public class Exercise1_3 {
 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int n=sc.nextInt();
     int sum=0;

     for(int i=0;i<n*2;i+=2)
     {
         System.out.println(i);
        if(i%3==0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
     }
     System.out.println(sum); 
 }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question in Nptel course in week1 3rd assignment and if you ask for that course, I hope you will pass with this answer,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_3 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int n=sc.nextInt();
      int sum=0;
      sum=-2;         //assign sum= -2 for start even values from 0
      int i=1;        //assign int i = 1 for using while
      int sumTemp=0;  //create sumTemp variable for store sum temporary value
           
           while(i<=n) {   
            sum=sum+2;   //sum will add +2 on it self for getting even numbers
             
             if(sum%3==0) {  
                 sumTemp=sum+sumTemp;  
             }i++;
        
           }
           sum=sumTemp;           // Store sum value from sumTemp

           System.out.print(sum); //finally print the sum
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have given he main idea, you can change input using scanner yourself.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int i=0;
        int num=0;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Even numbers");
        while(i<=10)
        {
            if(num%3 == 0)
            {

               sum += num;
            }

            i+=1;
            num+=2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand that if you are using for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) then you are check for only first 5 EVEN numbers, so you need to replace the loop to for(int i=0;i<=(2*n);i++).

Comment: Hi Tushar and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried running the code? Your example appears to fail to solve the problem for a very similar reason to OPs error. I suggest rereading the problem and providing a little more explanation for your answer.